# Using Laravel's Schema builder is there a way to do a ORDER BY FIELD query?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Is there a way to do a  ORDER BY FIELD query? This is what I currently have.

```
$sets = DB::connection('mysql')
            ->table('sets')
            ->orderBy('type', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('releaseDate', 'asc')
            ->select('code', 'type', 'name')
            ->get();
```

Or do I have to write the MySQL directly?

Comment: That should work.. are you seeing an error?

Comment: I know this works. I need to order by field. Something like. ->orderByField(type, 'Banana','Apple','Orange','Peach','Grape')

Comment: ah, sorry!  You can use `DB::raw()` to insert custom sql into the query.. one sec I'll post an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DB::raw()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions) to insert your ORDER BY FIELD clause:

```
$sets = DB::connection('mysql')
        ->table('sets')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(type, "Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Peach", "Grape")'))
        ->select('code', 'type', 'name')
        ->get();
```

Beware of SQL injection of course... And to check what the final SQL is, you can use the [Query Log](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#query-logging) after running the SQL:

```
$query_log = DB::getQueryLog();
```

Comment: This is perfect. How can I watch out for SQL injection in this case?

Comment: I just mean in general when using `DB::raw()`.. I don't know how you are going to populate that clause, but if you're accepting anything from the user: beware!

Comment: Ah ok, yeah in this case it's all server side. Thanks!